# How to make a DIV visible and invisible with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, visibility

Can you do something like

```js
function showDiv()
{
    [DIV].visible = true;
    //or something
}
```

Comment: Why not just use Jquery? .hide() ?

Comment: @JackStone: No, that's only if you're already using the jQuery library. Some people just like to promote it on every JavaScript question. Even if you were, `.hide()` doesn't set visibility. It sets display.

Comment: @am not i am you have clearly failed to understand that [jQuery is really great and does all things.](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif) [(Image source)](http://www.doxdesk.com/updates/2009.html#u20091116-jquery)

Comment: For something like this a good answer should contain both a plain JS solution and one showing the *advantage* of using a library - in this case, not having to deal with *inline vs block* when using `display` to show an element.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

if [DIV] is an element then

```
[DIV].style.visibility='visible'
```

OR

```
[DIV].style.visibility='hidden'
```

Comment: `visibility` has the side effect that the space occupied by the element remains reserved. That may or may not be what the OP wants

Comment: In the spot where it says [DIV], I would type the name of my div right?

Comment: No, use `document.getElementById('id-of-the-div')` instead of `[DIV]`

Comment: @JackStone: It depends on what you mean by the "name" of your div. If it's a variable that is referencing the div, then yes.

Comment: So if my div were name `testdiv`, it would be `document.getElementById('testdiv').style.visibility = 'hidden';`?

Comment: @user1163722: use "block"

Answer (score 152):

Let's assume you do not use a library such as jQuery.

If you do not already have a reference to the DOM element, get one using `var elem = document.getElementById('id');`

Then you can set any CSS property of that element. To show/hide, you can use two properties: `display` and `visibility`, which have slightly different effects:

Adjusting `style.display` will look as if element is not present at all ("removed").

```
elem.style.display = 'none'; // hide
elem.style.display = 'block'; // show - use this for block elements (div, p)
elem.style.display = 'inline'; // show - use this for inline elements (span, a)
```

or `style.visibility` will actually make the div still be there, but be "all empty" or "all white"

```
elem.style.visibility = 'hidden'; // hide, but lets the element keep its size
elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

---

If you are using jQuery, you can do it even easier as long as you want to set the `display` property:

```
$(elem).hide();
$(elem).show();
```

It will automatically use the appropriate `display` value; you do not have to care about the element type (inline or block). Additionally, `elem` can not only be a DOM element but also a selector such as `#id` or `.class` or anything else that is valid CSS3 (and more!).

Comment: I prefer your answer but I guess there is a little correction you have to use elem.style.display='none';

Comment: Sometimes it is acceptable to [assign an empty string to show an element](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21457904).

Comment: When would you use hidden instead of none regarding visibility?

Comment: When you want to hide the element but keep it in the layout (ie it'll still use space as if it was visible).

Comment: You can use .style.display=null instead .style.display="block" or "inline" or ... . When you use null, the default value is assigned according to the element type.

Answer (score 40):

You can use `visibility` or `display` but you have to apply changes to the `div.style` object and not the `div` object itself.

```
var div = document.getElementById('div_id');

// hide
div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
// OR
div.style.display = 'none';

// show
div.style.visibility = 'visible';
// OR
div.style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: wrong values for the labels. Those work now and no I'm not going to fiddle this, it's too simplistic.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the DOM functions: setAttribute and removeAttribute.
In the following link you have an example of how to use them.

[setAttribute and removeAttribute functions](https://jsfiddle.net/ve17c3yw/12/)

A quick view:

```
hide:    document.getElementById("myDiv").setAttribute("hidden","");
unhide:  document.getElementById("myDiv").removeAttribute("hidden");
```

Answer (score 3):

**as of November 2022 browser support for CSS revert value is 94.56%** (https://caniuse.com/?search=revert) so if for hiding you use

```
elem.style.display = 'none'; // hide
```

for visibility use

```
elem.style.display = 'revert'; // show
```

this posolite doesn't care about element type

> Note: The `revert` keyword is different from and should not be confused
> with the `initial` keyword, which uses the *initial value* defined on a
> per-property basis by the CSS specifications. In contrast, user-agent
> stylesheets set default values on the basis of CSS selectors.
>
> For example, the *initial value* for the `display` property is `inline`,
> whereas a normal user-agent stylesheet sets the default `display` value
> of `<div>`s to `block`, of `<table>`s to `table`, etc.
> [revert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert)

Answer (score 2):

**Make Invisible using CSS**

```
#div_id {
        /*height: 400px;*/
         visibility:hidden;
    }
```

**Make Visible using Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('div_id').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `opacity` which is similar to `visibility`  but allow to smooth transition and control other parameters like height (for snippet simplicity I put js logic in html directly - don't do it in production code)

```css
.box { width:150px; height: 150px; background: red; transition: 0.5s }

.hide { opacity: 0; height: 10px}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="box"></div>

<button onclick="box.classList.toggle('hide')">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 'hidden' attribute of DOM element:

```
function showDiv(isVisible)
{
    [DIV].hidden = !isVisible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ID is the name of your div. Make sure to have runat="server" in the Div.

```
            document.getElementById('<%= ID.ClientID %>').hidden = false;
         
            document.getElementById('<%= ID.ClientID %>').hidden = true;
```