# How to show a tab based on SELECT tag value in JSP?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

Hi I have created a JSP page. First tab contains a SELECT field. Based on the selected value I want to show the next tab. Can anyone help me please? I tried many times, but I am not getting.

```
<div class="navbar btn-navbar">
        <div id="tabs" class="tabbable">
            <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#datacollector" target="main"
                    data-toggle="tab">Data Collector</a></li>
                <li class="hidden"><a href="#fromDB" target="main"
                    data-toggle="tab">Data Load</a></li>
                <li class="hidden"><a href="#fromFile" target="main"
                    data-toggle="tab">Data Load</a></li>
                <li class="hidden"><a href="#email" target="main"
                    data-toggle="tab">Data Load</a></li>
                <li><a href="ajax/DataFieldMapping.jsp" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data
                        Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="#schedule" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Schedule</a></li>
            </ul>
            <br> <br> <br>
            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="datacollector">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span8">
                                <form name="selectType" action="selectType"
                                    onsubmit="return validateForm()" target="#fromDB" method="get">
                                    <fieldset>

                                        </select> <label class="control-label" for="dataloadType">Data
                                            load Type:</label> <select id="dataloadType" name="dataloadType">
                                            <option>Choose Data load Type</option>
                                            <option value="fromDB">From Database</option>
                                            <option value="fromFile">From File</option>
                                            <option value="email">E-mail</option>
                                            <option value="webServices">Web Services</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <p>
                                            <button id="nexttab" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                                        </p>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="fromDB">
                    <iframe src="GenericFileUpload.jsp" width="1250" height="400"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="fromFile">
                    <iframe src="GenericDB.jsp" width="1250" height="400"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="email">
                    <iframe src="EmailService.jsp" width="1250" height="400"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="datamap">
                    <iframe src="DataFieldMapping.jsp" width="1250" height="400"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="schedule">
                    <iframe src="UploadConfiguration.jsp" width="1250" height="400"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If the user selects **from File** it should show the next tab with id **fromFile** and also it should hide the tabs with ids **fromDB** and **email**. Can someone help me out?
How to do using Jquery?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Thanks. But its for tab demos only. I want to open a tab based on the selected value in the first tab

Comment: @ Shiju Please close the duplicate question of your own http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740397/how-to-show-a-tab-in-jsp-based-on-select-tag-value

Comment: I have deleted that. I don't got any answer so  asked again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to make a DIV visible and invisible with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456289/how-to-make-a-div-visible-and-invisible-with-javascript)

Just to add-on to this:

onchange event should be registered with a java-script function. This function will read the current selected value in the select box.

Based on the value, make only the div visible that's required, rest all to hidden.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#dataloadType').live('change',function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  $('#tabs').tabs('select',value);
});
```

Comment: What it will do is, when you change the select box having dataloadType as id, it will take the selected option value and select the tab having that value as id...So what error are you getting?