# Change element display none back to default style value JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function in JS that hides the element parsed:

```
function hide(id){
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}
```

How can I create a function that brings back the element to the default style value. For instance a div `display` property is `"block"` as for an image is `"inline-block"`, other elements are `"inline"` or lists are `"list-item"` How can I bring them back their default state?

```
function show(id){
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "?????";
}
```

**I know how to do it in Jquery but it is not an option.**

In CSS there might be styles for the elements including `style:none`, which need to be overwritten to the default value.

Since there is CSS in my example making `style.display = ''` eliminates the style added with JS but gets back to whatever style is added in CSS, I want to bring it back to its default value even before assigning styles with CSS.

I tried this as it was suggested in a link in one of the comments:

```
elem = document.getElementById(id);
var theCSSprop = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null).getPropertyValue("display");
```

but in this case `'theCSSprop'` returns `"none"` for a `div`, when I expect `"block"`

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: I would add/remove classes. [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need just assign it to empty value:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display = "";
```

Or using `removeProperty` method:

```
document.getElementById(id).style.removeProperty( 'display' );
```

But note that `removeProperty` will not work on `IE<9`.

If you want to get original CSS value you will need probably to get it from empty `<iframe>` element. I created [example](http://jsfiddle.net/LcZpc/) on jsFiddle how to get current value using `getComputedStyle` and iframe value on jsFiddle.

Please note that `getComputedStyle` not support old versions of IE. It support IE9+.

For IE8 you should use [`Element.currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This works well because it just removes the display property from the inline styles so the display goes back to what it was defined in the css

Comment: Thanks, I see your point and it works, except that in css I may have display:none; so by doing style.display = ""; it takes back the style from the CSS stylesheet and not the elements default value. I changed my question as well. Thanks!

Comment: @EddyXP also you can try https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.getComputedStyle method

Comment: @antyrat, thanks you. as I mentioned before your answer solves the problem if there default styles have not been modified in a CSS stylesheet, I tried the link you shared and it returns 'null', look at my answer, can you provide a working example? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Note:
If you define **display:none;** for a class or tag (either in a separate css file or in the *head* section), the above methods won't work.

Then you will have to determine which type of tag + class it is and manually assign the value specific to it.

---

These are examples of what may not work:

```
// In many cases this won't work:
function ShowHide_WillRarelyWork(id, bDisplay) {
    // Note: This will fail if parent is of other tag than element.
    var o = document.getElementById(id);
    if (o == null) return;
    //
    if (bDisplay) {
        o.style.display = 'inherit';
        o.style.visibility = true;
    }
    else {
        o.style.display = 'none';
    }
} // ShowHide_WillRarelyWork(...)

// This will work in most, but not all, cases:
function ShowHide_MayWork(id, bDisplay) {
    // Note: This will fail if element is declared as 'none' in css.
    var o = document.getElementById(id);
    if (o == null) return;
    //
    if (bDisplay) {
        o.style.display = null;
        o.style.visibility = true;
    }
    else {
        o.style.display = 'none';
    }
} // ShowHide_MayWork(...)
```

This is long but will most probably work:

```
function getDefaultDisplayByTag(sTag) {
    // This is not fully implemented, as that would be very long...
    // See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html for full list.
    switch (sTag) {
        case 'div':
        case 'ul':
        case 'h1':
        case 'h2':
        case 'h3':
        case 'h4':
        case 'h5':
        case 'h6':      return 'block';
        //
        case 'li':      return 'list-item';
        //
        case 'table':   return 'table';
        //
        case 'td':
        case 'th':      return 'table-cell';
    }
    // Fallback:
    return 'block';
} // getDefaultDisplayByTag(...)
//
function computeDisplay(o) {
    var oFunction = window.getComputedStyle;
    if (oFunction) {
        var oStyle = window.getComputedStyle(o)
        if ((oStyle) && (oStyle.getPropertyValue)) {
            return oStyle.getPropertyValue('display');
        }
    }
    if (window.currentStyle) {
        return window.currentStyle.display;
    }
    return null; // <-- This is going to be a bad day...
} // computeStyle(...)
//
// This will most probably work:
function ShowHideObject_WillProbablyWork(o, bDisplay, bMaybeRecursive) {
    if ((o == null) || (o == undefined) || (o == document) || (o.tagName == undefined)) return;
    //
    if (bDisplay == null) bDisplay = true
    if (!bDisplay) {
        o.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        // First remove any directly set display:none;
        if ((o.style.display == 'none') || (o.style.display == '')) {
            o.style.display = null;
        }
        //
        var sDisplay = null;
        var sDisplayCurrent = computeDisplay(o);
        var oParent = o.parentNode;
        // Was this element hidden via css?
        if ((sDisplayCurrent == null) || (sDisplayCurrent == 'none')) {
            // We must determing a sensible display value:
            var sTag = o.tagName;
            sDisplay = getDefaultDisplayByTag(sTag);
        } // else: if ((sDisplayCurrent != null) && (sDisplayCurrent != 'none'))
        //
        // Make sure visibility is also on:
        if (sDisplay != null) o.style.display = sDisplay;
        o.style.visibility = true;
        //
        if (bMaybeRecursive) {
            // We should travel up the tree and make sure parent are also displayed:
            ShowHideObject_WillProbablyWork(oParent, true, true);
        }
    } // else: if (!bDisplay) ...
    //
} // ShowHideObject_WillProbablyWork(...)
//
// ... and finally:
function ShowHideId_WillProbablyWork(id, bDisplay, bMaybeRecursive)
    var o = document.getElementById(id);
    ShowHideObject_WillProbablyWork(o, bDisplay, bMaybeRecursive)
} // ShowHideId_WillProbablyWork(...)
```

Of course this could be shortened a bit; but that's how it looks in my source.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more solution for retrieving any property default value of any element. Idea is following:

1. Get nodeName of specific element
2. Append a fake element of the same node name to body
3. Get any property value of the fake element.
4. Remove fake element.

```js
function getDefaultValue(element, property) {
    var elDefault = document.createElement(element.nodeName);
    document.body.appendChild(elDefault);
    propertyValue = window.getComputedStyle(elDefault,null).getPropertyValue(property);
    document.body.removeChild(elDefault);
  return propertyValue;
}
 function resetPropertyValue (element,propertyName) {
    var propertyDefaultValue = getDefaultValue(element, propertyName);
    if (element.style.setProperty) {
        element.style.setProperty (propertyName, propertyDefaultValue, null);
    } 
    else {
        element.style.setAttribute (propertyName, propertyDefaultValue);
    }
}
```

```css
#d {
  background: teal;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="resetPropertyValue(document.getElementById('d'), 'display')">Try it</button>
<div id="d">test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom attributes

```
function hide(id){
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    //Store prev value
    elem.setAttribute('custom-attr', elem.style.display);
    elem.style.display = "none";
}

function show(id){
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    //Set prev value
    elem.style.display = elem.getAttribute('custom-attr');
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to use a data attribute, which is a valid attribute that's meant to be used for such cases. So, instead of "custom-attr", simply use "data-olddisplay" or something alike.

Comment: this doesnt work if u call hide twice, and with elements initliazed as hidden, because u dont have the attr

Answer (score 0):

Filling in an empty value removes the inline override, so the original value is active again.

```
function show(id){
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "";
}
```

Comment: None of the above solutions work if a style is manually specified in <style> section as ‘display:none’. There is the official list of the default CSS values for each HTML element, but it is unbelievable that JS has no option to switch back to it or at least to determine which one is the default one for a current element.

Answer (score -1):

Since what you want is the default value for the element and not what's in the style sheet, you simply want to set the value to auto.

```
document.getElementById(id).style.display="auto"
```

This tells the browser to calculate what the normal display for this type of element is and to use that.

Comment: `auto` is not a valid value for `display`. Perhaps you mean `initial`?