# Having trouble making an image disappear when using onmouseover event on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, html

I'm having trouble making an image disappear while using an onmouseover event not on it, but on a button element. I need it to appear while onmouseover and disappear while not onmouseover. Heres my code:

```
    <script>
  function sfunc1() {
    var x = document.getElementById('imgSWTCH1');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
function sfunc2() {
  var x = document.getElementById('imgSWTCH2');
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
      x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
      x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
function sfunc3() {
  var x = document.getElementById('imgSWTCH3');
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
      x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
      x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
function sfunc4() {
  var x = document.getElementById('imgSWTCH4');
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
      x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
      x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
function sfunc5() {
  var x = document.getElementById('imgSWTCH5');
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
      x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
      x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
function sfunc6() {
  var x = document.getElementById('imgSWTCH6');
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
      x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
      x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
function sfunc7() {
  var x = document.getElementById('imgSWTCH7');
  if (x.style.display === 'none') {
      x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
      x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
</script>
```

This is the javascript to make it appear on mouseover, and the html is

```
  <img id="imgSWTCH1"src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/10/20/846459_blue_512x512.png" width="100" height="100"/>
        <img id="imgSWTCH2"src="https://www.writeraccess.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/blog-html-5.png" width="100" height="100"/>
        <img id="imgSWTCH3"src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/06/25/619190_java_256x256.png" width="100" height="100"/>
        <img id="imgSWTCH4"src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/05/06/760855_css_512x512.png" width="100" height="100"/>
        <img id="imgSWTCH5"src="http://poiemaweb.com/img/socketio-logo.png" width="100" height="100"/>
        <img id="imgSWTCH6"src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/07/08/116973_development_512x512.png" width="100" height="100"/>
        <img id="imgSWTCH7"src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2015/08/30/93000_javascript_512x512.png" width="100" height="100"/>
        <center>


          <br />
          <br />
          <table >
              <tb id="tab" onmouseover="sfunc1()" onmouseout="this.className='BO';">C</tb>

              <br />
                <tb id="tab" onmouseover=" sfunc3()" onmouseout="this.className='BO';">Java</tb>
                  <tb id="tab" onmouseover=" sfunc2()" onmouseout="this.className='BO';">HTML</tb>
                    <tb id="tab" onmouseover="sfunc4()" onmouseout="this.className='BO';">CSS</tb>

                      <tb id="tab" onmouseover="sfunc5()" onmouseout="this.className='BO';">Socket.io/Node</tb>
                        <tb id="tab" onmouseover="sfunc6()" onmouseout="this.className='BO';">Angular.js</tb>
                        <br />
                           <tb id="tab" onmouseover="sfunc7()" onmouseout="this.className='BO';">Javascript</tb>

                            <tb id="tab" onmouseover=" this.className='BC';" onmouseout="this.className='BO';">and much more!</tb>
          </table>
          </center>
```

The onmouseout for all of these just makes the background orange but I want it to make the image corresponding to it disappear, which I'm having trouble with since you cant assign multiple ID's to an element. A jquery solution would work too, and so would one in angular.
https://plnkr.co/edit/WwpzOkipsiCrbgbpXbd4?p=preview
heres the pnlkr link, stetch the html portion out to see the whole thing too.

Comment: FYI IDs are meant to be unique as in two elements should not have the same ID.

Comment: can you create a plnkr/jsfiddle instead to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example using JQuery:

https://jsfiddle.net/ztuf96dg/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').hover(function(e) {
      var imageID = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-img-id');
      var $image = $('img[data-img-id="' + imageID + '"]');
      $image.show();
    },
    function(e) {
      var imageID = $(e.currentTarget).attr('data-img-id');
      var $image = $('img[data-img-id="' + imageID + '"]');
      $image.hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes way more sense! But I want it to do the opposite, as in start invisible and on mouse over become visible.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it with one function for mouseover and one for mouseout. Also use the visibility property of the img instead of display to prevent the elements jumping.

```
See it here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/YeOgtFeEmNhRCgdQ0Mlp?p=preview
```

**EDIT**

So the point is:

```
  function sfuncOver(imgId) {
    var x = document.getElementById(imgId);
    if (x.style.visibility === 'hidden') {
        x.style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        x.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
  }

  function sfuncOut(imgId) {
    var x = document.getElementById(imgId);
    x.style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
```

...in js and in html:

```
 <td id="tab1" onmouseover="sfuncOver('imgSWTCH1')" onmouseout="sfuncOut('imgSWTCH1')">C</td>
```

...and so on. BUT doing this with jQuery would be 10 thousands better :) This is the coding style of the 90s :)

Answer (score 0):

You have 7 functions doing the same exact thing. A better approach may be to create one function and bind what element you want to hide to it. Here is a fiddle with an example: https://jsfiddle.net/83drj2rs/1/

Here is the corresponding JavaScript:

```
function toggleVisibility(element){
    if(element.style.display === "none") {
    element.style.display = "inline-block";
  } else {
    element.style.display = "none";
  }
}

Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('tab')).forEach(function(element){
    element.onmouseover = toggleVisibility.bind(this, document.getElementById(element.getAttribute('data-hide')));
});
```

Also note that I removed all of your `onmouseover` attributes on the html elements themselves and replaced them with a `data-hide` attribute instead. This tells the function which element to hide on the mouseover event.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

HMTL:

```
<table >
              <tb id="tab1">C</tb> //make sure id is unique for each <tb>
              <br />
                (...)
          </table>
```

Javascript:
(*)make sure you wrap javascript on document ready.

```
$(function() {
  $('#imgSWTCH1').hide();  
  $('#tab1').mouseover(function (e) {
     //e.stopPropagation();
      $('#imgSWTCH1').show();      
  });
  $('#tab1').mouseout(function (e) {
    //e.stopPropagation();
      $('#imgSWTCH1').hide();      
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```js
var change=function(){
    if(document.getElementById("image").style.visibility == "visible"){
        document.getElementById("image").style.visibility = "hidden";}else{document.getElementById("image").style.visibility="visible";}
    }
function enter(){
    document.getElementById("image").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
function leave(){
    document.getElementById("image").style.visibility="visible";
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
 <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<img onmouseover="enter();" onmouseout="leave();" id="image" src="https://publicdomainvectors.org/photos/Microscope-BW.png"/>
<button onclick="change();" >ClicMe</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Run the code snnipet
Hope it does it...Good Luck

Comment: References...[Changing Visibility Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456289/how-to-make-a-div-visible-and-invisible-with-javascript#9456325) and [onmouseover w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onmouseover.asp)